# C++ Pimpl vs Pure Virtual Interface Performance

Tags: c++, performance, cross-platform, virtual-functions, pimpl-idiom

I realize there are quite a few posts on this subject, but I am having trouble finding the answer to this exact question.

For function calls, which is faster, a pure-virtual interface or a pimpl?

At first glance, it seems to me that the pure-virtual interface would be faster, because the using the pimpl would cost two function calls instead of one...or would some kind of clever compiler trick take over in this case?

edit:
I am trying to decide which of these I should use to abstract away the system-dependent portions of a few objects that may end up having to be spawned quite frequently, and in large numbers.

**edit:**
I suppose it's worth saying at this point, that the root of my problem was that I mistook the Abstract Factory design pattern for a method of making my code work on multiple platforms, when it's real purpose is for switching implementations for a given interface at **runtime.**

Comment: When using pimpl, the public interface's methods could be inlined, so the performance difference would be almost none.

Comment: System task are going to be heavy in cost so the cost of the function call it-self will be immeasurable (unless you can show it is not). So you should not be using this as your decision making criteria. Choose the one that makes writing the code the easiest and simplist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two options are not equivalent, they should not be compared on performance as the focus is different. Even if they were equivalent, the performance difference would be minimal to unimportant in most situations. If you are in the rare case that you *know* that dispatch is being an issue, then you have the tools to measure the difference yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you ask? The question doesn't seem to make sense.

One generally uses virtual functions when one wants polymorphism: when you want them to be overridden in derived classes.

One generally uses pimpl when one wants to remove implementation details from header files.

The two really aren't interchangeable. Off the top of my head, I cannot think of any reasonable situations where you would use one and consider replacing it with the other.

---

Anyways, that said, for a typical implementation of virtual functions, a function call involves reading the object to find the virtual function table pointer, then reading the virtual function table to find the function pointer, and finally calling the function pointer.

For a class implemented via pimpl, one function call is forced, but it could be absolutely anything 'under the hood'. Despite what you suggest, no second function call is implied by the paradigm.

---

Finally, don't forget the usual guidelines for optimization apply: you have to actually implement and measure. Trying to "think" up the answer tends to lead to poor results, even from people experienced at this sort of thing.

And, of course, the most important rule of optimization: make sure something matters before you devote a lot of time trying to optimize it. Otherwise, you are going to wind up wasting a lot of time and energy.